# How to solve trigonometric matrix

Tags: matrix

I need help for my problem according to matrix.

Given a matrix,

```
A = ( {
    {E^(I \[Beta]1 + I \[Beta]3) Cos[\[Beta]2 Degree], 
     E^(I \[Beta]1 - I \[Beta]3)  Sin[\[Beta]2 Degree]},
    {-E^(-I \[Beta]1 + I \[Beta]3)  Sin[\[Beta]2 Degree], 
     E^(-I \[Beta]1 - I \[Beta]3)  Cos[\[Beta]2 Degree]}
   } );
```

I want to find value for this matrix with value of [Beta]1 = 0 and [Beta]3 = 0 and change of value of [Beta]2 = 0, given coding below.

```
For[i = 1; [Beta]1 = 0; [Beta]2 = 0; [Beta]3 = 0, i < 7, 
 i++, [Beta]2 = [Beta]2 + 15; A; Print[A]]
```

I get the result as below,

```
{{1,0},{0,1}}

{{1,0},{0,1}}

{{1,0},{0,1}}

{{1,0},{0,1}}

{{1,0},{0,1}}

{{1,0},{0,1}}
```

Suppose the value will change but it retain the same.

Can anyone help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = {{Exp[I β1 + I β3] Cos[β2 Degree], Exp[I β1 - I β3] Sin[β2 Degree]}, {-Exp[-I β1 + I β3] Sin[β2 Degree], 
     Exp[-I β1 - I β3] Cos[β2 Degree]}} /. {β1 -> 0, β3 -> 0};

β2 = 0;
For[i = 1, i < 7, i++, β2 = β2 + 15; Print[A]]
```

[image]

**update**

```
β2 = 15;
For[i = 1, i < 7, i++, β2 = β2 + 15; Print[A // N]]
```

[image]

Comment: Now, I need extra help. Let say the value of β1=0 and β3=0 and β2=15 
A = {{Exp[I β1 + I β3] Cos[β2 Degree], Exp[I β1 - I β3] Sin[β2 Degree]}, {-Exp[-I β1 + I β3] Sin[β2 Degree], 
     Exp[-I β1 - I β3] Cos[β2 Degree]}}

Comment: Thank you rewi . sorry because I enter the extra question wihout finished it first.  
Now, β1=0,β2=15,β3=0 and only β2 dependent on time.
A = {{Exp[I β1 + I β3] Cos[β2t Degree], Exp[I β1 - I β3] Sin[β2t Degree]}, {-Exp[-I β1 + I β3] Sin[β2t Degree],                                                     For[i = 1, i < 7, i++;t++, t=t+TimeUsed[]; Print[A]]. I want to look the changes of  β2 only on time(t=0s until t=10s). I want to know, the TimeUsed can be used ? Because I want to look the value with fix β1 and β3 and dependent β2 with time. tq

Comment: A = ( {
     {E^(I \[Beta]1 + I \[Beta]3) Cos[\[Beta]2t], 
      E^(I \[Beta]1 - I \[Beta]3)  Sin[\[Beta]2t]},
     {-E^(-I \[Beta]1 + I \[Beta]3)  Sin[\[Beta]2t], 
      E^(-I \[Beta]1 - I \[Beta]3)  Cos[\[Beta]2t]}
    } ) /. {\[Beta]1 -> 0, \[Beta]3 -> 0};

\[Beta]2 = 0;

For[i = 1; t = TimeUsed, i < 7; t < 11, i++, t = t + TimeUsed[]; 
 Print[A]; Print[t]]. I cannot run this. please help me

Comment: @munirah This question is very different from the 1st question. Please make a new question so others can solve it too.